# See if point lies inside a certain percentage of a circle

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I have a problem in math for myself. I know how to check if a point lies inside a circle: `(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 <= r^2`

But my problem is a bit diferent. I have a certain percentage of a circle: the circle is not full, it's just part of it (it's like a progress pie).

I need to see if a point is inside that percentage.

How to do that, what is the formula?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#define pi 3.14159265
using namespace std;
ifstream fin("sol.in");
ofstream fout("sol.out");
int x,y,p,t,i;
double phi;
int main()
{
    fin>>t;
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        fin>>p>>x>>y;
        phi=atan2(50-y,50-x);
        if(phi<0)phi+=2*pi;
        if(phi<2*pi*p)cout<<"1"<<endl;
        else cout<<"0"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My input file:

5
0 55 55
12 55 55
13 55 55
99 99 99
87 20 40

Comment: What data is given to specify the pie? Do you know how to compute angles?

Comment: i don't know how to compute angles, to specify the pie there is a percentage p

Comment: If your center of the circle is `50,50`, then it should be `atan2(y-50, x-50)`.

Comment: Or alternatively, but needing some comments for later comprehension, `phi=atan2(50-y,50-x)+pi` which will always give a non-negative angle, so that the correction in the next line is not necessary.

Comment: Simplification: `r=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));` --> `r = hypot(x, y);`

Comment: Do not update your question with the answer. Post rolled back.   It makes the all ready posted answers confusing.  Should you want to answer your own question, post that as an answer below - you can even accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the angle as

```
phi = atan2(y-y1, x-x1);
if(phi<0) phi += 2*Pi;
```

and compare

```
phi < 2*Pi*percentage
```

Comment: Wait something doesn't work right. When i compare phi < 2*Pi*percentage

Comment: I have edited my answer and there is also my c++ code

Answer (score 0):

Work in polar coordinate system.

In such a system, an `M` point is represented by a `(r, t)` couple, where `r` is the distance from the `O` origin to `M`, and `t` is the counterclockwise angle between the x axis and the `(OM)` line.

Besides, `r` is strictly positive, and `t` is in `[0, 2*Pi[` (in the representation I chose), and is in radian.

From a Cartesian coordinate system, the polar coordinates are gotten as follows:

> r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
>
> t = atan2(-y, -x) + Pi

(More on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates))

---

I'll assume you are counting your percentage of circle from the x axis, in the trigonometric direction, so you'll have something like this:

[image: 0.6 circle]

First, if `r` is greater than your circle's radius, then `M` is outside of the circle.

Else, suppose you have a `p` proportion of circle, such that `0 <= p <= 1`. In radian, this is equal to `2*Pi*p`.

Since `t` and `2*Pi*p` are both in the `[0, 2*Pi[` range, you can directly compare them: if `t > 2*Pi*p`, then `M` is outside of the circle.

---

Now for the formula, if you have a `(x, y)` point and a `(R, p)` circle of `R` radius and `p` percentage, a necessary and sufficient condition would be:

```
(x, y) in (R, p) <=> sqrt(x^2 + y^2) <= R AND atan2(-y, -x) + Pi <= 2*Pi*p
```

Comment: The values of `atan2` are in the range `[-Pi, Pi]`, you will need to correct for that.

Comment: You still want that the angle of (1,0) is 0. To avoid post-processing, you could use `atan2(-y,-x)+Pi`.

Comment: @LutzL I'm trusting you. To be honest, I'm not used to this `atan2` function, it's a bit different from the conventions I was using in class. Thanks for helping me improve my answer though :)

Comment: `atan2(y,x)` returns just the angle of the point `(x,y)` or the argument of the complex number `x+i*y`. As `(-x,-y)` is the opposite point, it is rotated by +pi or -pi. Using that is not the most transparent formula.

Comment: what if the percentage goes not in a trigonometric way but in the clock way, what i need to change for that?

Comment: I've edited my code, can you please tell me what's wrong, it is saying just 0, when there needs to be and ones

Comment: @Victor : Change the sign of `y`. That is, instead of `atan2(y,x)` compute `atan2(-y,x)`. Or changing the formula in the post above, `atan2(y,-x)+Pi`.

Comment: i did it and is sill not going well, may be becasue i need anoter formula for clockwise percentage, not trigonometric

Comment: Can you please help me